# Change 1:M relationship to M:M in an Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a question about how to change relationships between tales in an Oracle database while preserving existing data.

Let's say I want to represent People and Employers such that each person works for a single employer. I do this with a PERSON table and an EMPLOYER table with a 1:M relationship of EMPLOYER to PERSON. The PERSON table had columns ID, NAME, and EMPLOYER_ID, and the EMPLOYER table had columns ID, NAME, AND LOCATION.

If I wanted to update this schema so a PERSON can work for more than one EMPLOYER, I could add a PERSON_EMPLOYER table with columns for each ID.

Could anyone give some pointers on the most sensible way to do this and move my existing data in? I think I can add a join table, but I'm not sure how to populate it with existing employer:employer data. After that I guess I remove EMPLOYER_ID column from PERSON.

Should I just be backing up the database and doing this operation in a script?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your `person` table already has both ID values you need to populate your new `person_employee` table, so I'm not sure what else you think you need? Backing up - or at least exporting or making copies of the tables - seems like a good idea though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a backup is always a good idea.
But in my opinion transferring data from one table to another it is quite reliable operation.  You do not necessary make a script, just do it step by step and check changes.

1. Create a new PERSON_EMPLOYER table
2. Copy existing data to PERSON_EMPLOYER table.
3. COMMIT data changes.
4. Check data in PERSON_EMPLOYER table
5. Drop EMPLOYER_ID column from PERSON table. (No need to remove the column immediately, it can be done later when you will be sure that everything is fine with the your data.)

For transferring data from PERSON table  to PERSON_EMPLOYER table  you can use simple INSERT

```
INSERT INTO employer_person (employer_id, person_id)  
    SELECT employer_id, person_id FROM person;
```

Do not forget COMMIT this operation!